# How to use calendar in Sharepoint 2010 webpart‏

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am new to sharepoint. Please help me on the following problem

I want a calendar  icon beside textbox, when I click on the calender icon and select date it gets populated in textbox. This has to be done preferably done by using Sharepoint Calendar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateTime Picker Control of a SharePoint.

See below given example
http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/10/using-sharepoint-date-control-in-web.html